# How to programatically add liferay portlet Instance dynamically and install the portlet to the to dashboard page on click of a button?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have a liferay portlet instance created dynamically and added to the layout programatically as follows

```
String portletId = objUtil.addPortlet("/prj/reports", "XYZPortlet_WAR_ecpmportlet", "column-2",groupId, "type: " + getSelectedType());
```

So it adds a portlet to the `/reports` page.
I want to add a button below the portlet called <kbd>send to dashboard</kbd> on clicking the button I want to install this portlet to the user dashboard permanently.

***Note:*** There can any number of portlet instances added to the `/report`s page.

As you see XYZPortlet is the id of the portlet defined in liferay-portlet.xml, liferay-display.xml which remains same for all the portlets I add to the reports page.

I want to dynamically assign a new Id to the portlet instance and install it permanently to the dashboard layout.

Can anyone please suggest a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you have try yet and what fails?

Comment: @mark I need to install the portlet instance added to reports page to the users dashboard..

Comment: @PadmanabhaVn what do you mean by statement "I want to dynamically assign a new Id to the portlet instance"? Can you please give clarification on that.?

Comment: @PankajKathiriya .. we have entry for portlet in xml files and we are creating an instance of that portlet and adding it using addPortlet function.. so we want this instance to be given new name and install it permanently to dashboard layout and we want it to be appear in more portlets dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple get the global portletId and add it to user home page:

```
LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = (LayoutTypePortlet) userlayout.getLayoutType();
String portletInstanceId = layoutTypePortlet.addPortletId(0, portletId, columnId, -1, false);
LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(userlayout.getGroupId(), userlayout.isPrivateLayout(), userlayout.getLayoutId(), userlayout.getTypeSettings());
```

Comment: 1. Get the `Layout` object from the user homepage (dashboard). 2. Get `LayoutTypePortlet` and put the `portletId` to clumn where the portlet should be placed. 3. Save the changes. Finish.

Comment: thanks for the reply mark .. I want to add many such portlets to dashboard  and I want the portlets to be appear in more portlets dropdown.. will it be possible ?

Comment: what is the portletId in this line `layoutTypePortlet.addPortletId(0, portletId, columnId, -1, false);`